# Can I use JavaScript to generate an RSS (XML) page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, rss

I'm looking to retrieve JSON (from a third-party website) and convert it into a valid RSS/XML feed.

Is this possible?

Can RSS readers read pages that are basically only javascript generating a web page?

Are there other options to convert a JSON web page to RSS?  (ie. retrieve the JSON using an HTTP request and then return valid RSS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can RSS readers read pages that are basically only javascript generating a web page?

No. RSS is a XML-based file format; as far as I know, it does not support Javascript in any form.

You will need server-side scripting to do the conversion.

Comment: This, I believe is the relevant part to the question. +1

Comment: RSS readers can read anything that's in RSS format, no matter how it was produced. But there is no JSON equivalent to RSS, though it is possible to map RSS onto JSON (and vice versa). What you come up with is something that no one can read. I was experimenting with this on scripting.com a couple of weeks ago. http://scripting.com/stories/2010/10/09/nextStepsInTheFeedhoseProj.html

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty much convert anything into anything if you have enough input data :)
The question is what are you trying to achieve?

If you want persistency, you will very likely have to do that from a server side.